# How can I print the bits of a __m128i variable in C?

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics

I don't have any idea how to print the bits of a __m128i variable in C
so feel free to tell me your ideas!

Thank you!

Comment: Please try something, if it does not work post the code, and ask a proper question.

Comment: You could use a simple loop, where each iteration extracts the high bit, prints it, and left shifts the binary value one bit.

Answer (score 3):

However you do that is going to be an awful hack. Off the top of my head (__m128i is a 128-bit/ 16-byte aligned type) I can think of this:

```
__m128i toPrint;
char * bytearray = (char *) &toPrint;
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%02hhx", bytearray[i]);
```

This prints it in hexadecimal, but it is ugly.

Comment: Works fine but I don't like the hexadecimal output.

Comment: Well if you need it in binary for whatever reason, then replace the printf call above with the uglier nested loop as follows:
`for(int j = 0; j < CHAR_BIT, j++) printf("%hhu", (bytearray[i] & (1 << j)) ? 1 : 0);`

Answer (score 2):

In order to print the bits, I implemented the following program.

```
//Linx-mint 18.1, gcc 6.2, Skylake.
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void printVec8(__m128i vec)
{
    int i;
    char array[16];
    _mm_store_si128( (__m128i *) array, vec);
    for(i=0; i<16; i++){
        printf("%3u , " , array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
inline void vec_print_128Bits(__m128i vec)
{
    __m128i bit0, bit1, bit2, bit3, bit4, bit5, bit6, bit7;
    __m128i mask = _mm_set_epi8(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
    //fisrt separate them and print to check them:
    bit0 = _mm_and_si128(vec , mask);                   printf("bit0 :"); printVec8(bit0);
    bit1 = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srai_epi16(vec,1) , mask); printf("bit1 :"); printVec8(bit1);
    bit2 = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srai_epi16(vec,2) , mask); printf("bit2 :"); printVec8(bit2);
    bit3 = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srai_epi16(vec,3) , mask); printf("bit3 :"); printVec8(bit3);
    bit4 = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srai_epi16(vec,4) , mask); printf("bit4 :"); printVec8(bit4);
    bit5 = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srai_epi16(vec,5) , mask); printf("bit5 :"); printVec8(bit5);
    bit6 = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srai_epi16(vec,6) , mask); printf("bit6 :"); printVec8(bit6);
    bit7 = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srai_epi16(vec,7) , mask); printf("bit7 :"); printVec8(bit7);

    //now store them in array
    char bits[8][16];
    _mm_store_si128( (__m128i *) bits[0], bit0);
    _mm_store_si128( (__m128i *) bits[1], bit1);
    _mm_store_si128( (__m128i *) bits[2], bit2);
    _mm_store_si128( (__m128i *) bits[3], bit3);
    _mm_store_si128( (__m128i *) bits[4], bit4);
    _mm_store_si128( (__m128i *) bits[5], bit5);
    _mm_store_si128( (__m128i *) bits[6], bit6);
    _mm_store_si128( (__m128i *) bits[7], bit7);

    //and now print them all:
    int i, j;
    printf("all bits : \n");
    for(i=0; i<16; i++){
        for( j=7; j>=0; j--)
        {
            printf("%u ", bits[j][i]);
        }
        //printf("\n");
    }


}

int main()
{


    __m128i vec = _mm_setr_epi8(0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0x0B,0x0C,0x0D,0x0E,0x0F); printf("vec  :"); printVec8(vec);

    vec_print_128Bits(vec); 


    return 0;
}
```

And the out put is :

```
vec  :  0 ,   1 ,   2 ,   3 ,   4 ,   5 ,   6 ,   7 ,   8 ,   9 ,  10 ,  11 ,  12 ,  13 ,  14 ,  15 , 
bit0 :  0 ,   1 ,   0 ,   1 ,   0 ,   1 ,   0 ,   1 ,   0 ,   1 ,   0 ,   1 ,   0 ,   1 ,   0 ,   1 , 
bit1 :  0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 , 
bit2 :  0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 , 
bit3 :  0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 ,   1 , 
bit4 :  0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 , 
bit5 :  0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 , 
bit6 :  0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 , 
bit7 :  0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 , 
all bits : 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: The first part (until //now store them in array) works fine. The rest gives me an error..

Comment: @Sofia, use `_mm_storeu_si128`instead and tell me if the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive function to print all 128 bits of an `__m128i` integer value.

```
// Private helper function
static void print_128_bitsH(__m128i val, int depth)
{
    if (depth > 0)
        print_128_bitsH(val >> 1, depth - 1);
    printf("%d", (int)(val & 1));
}

// Print 128 bits, from most significant to least significant
void print_128_bits(__m128i val)
{
    print_128_bitsH(val, 128);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This is a lot cleaner than my example.

Comment: This can also be done in a single function with a single loop, but the recursive solution is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not much different than printing the bits of a 32-bit integer.  Stash the 128-bit vector to four 32-bit integers and then print the bits of each of them in order.

```
void print_bits128(__m128i v) {
  int t[4];
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)t, v);
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    int num = t[i];
    for(int j=0; j<32; j++){
      printf("%u",num&0x80000000 ? 1 : 0);
      num <<= 1;
    }
  }
  puts("");
}
```